# Explanation of a particular piece of C*-algebra notation

Tags: notation, c-star-algebras

For this question, $A$ is a given (possibly non-unital) [$C^*$-algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C*-algebra) and $p$ is an element of the [multiplier algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplier_algebra), $M(A)$, satisfying $p^2=p=p^*$ (ie is a *projection*). $M(A)$ is most easily described as linear right-$A$-module maps $A\to A$ with an adjoint with respect to the $A$-valued inner product $\langle a , b \rangle_A := a^*b$ on $A$.

Recall that $A$ is an ideal in $M(A)$, so elements of $A$ can be considered as multipliers (acting on the left: $m_a \cdot b = ab$). If $p\in A$, then one can consider the [corner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hereditary_C*-subalgebra#Connections_with_positive_elements) $pAp$, which is the subalgebra of elements of the form $pap$, for $a$ in $A$. Likewise, there is the two-sided ideal $ApA$, which is the span of elements of the form $a_1pa_2$, for $a_1,a_2 \in A$. There is also the right ideal $pA$, with elements $pa$.

However, these notations are also used for arbitrary projections $p$ in $M(A)$. It is not entirely clear to me what sets $pAp$ and $ApA$ are supposed to be. The right ideal $pA$ is not so mysterious, since one can describe it as the image of the linear map $p\colon A \to A$ (and, in that case, $A \simeq pA \oplus (id - p)A$ as  <strike>`C^*`-algebras</strike> topological vector spaces).

> What is a concrete description of $pAp$ and $ApA$ when $p$ is some projection in $M(A)$?

Answer (score 1):

You say that $M(A)$ is "most easily" described, and I have to disagree. In my opinion, $M(A)$ is most easily described by considering any faithful non-degenerate representation $A\subset B(H)$, and taking $$\tag1M(A)=\{T\in B(H):\ Ta\in A,\ aT\in A,\ \text{ for all } a\in A\}.$$

Since $A\subset M(A)$ as an ideal, the products $pap$ and $apb$ are perfectly well defined for any $p\in M(A)$ and $a,b\in A$. I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "concrete": most elements in most C$^*$-algebras are not "concrete" if you mean that you can write them explicitly (note that this assertion is even true in the case of the real numbers).

One can play the game of using a concrete construction of $M(A)$ and try to write $pAp$ "explicitly"; this could be an interesting exercise in formalism, but it won't clarify anything. For instance, using your picture you first need to see $A$ inside $M(A)$. As you said, $a$ corresponds to $m_a$. So if $p\in M(A)$ is a projection, you have $p^2=p^*=p$. The fact that $p=p^*$ means that $p(a)^*b=a^*p(b)$ for all $a,b\in A$. And $pap:A\to A$ is the map 
$$
(pap)b=p(ap(b))=p(a)p(b)
$$
(remember that $p$ is a right $A$-module map). Not very concrete.

Finally, you say that $A\simeq pA\oplus (I-P)A$ "as C$^*$-algebras"). Note that $pA$ is a right ideal, not a subalgebra.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I meant as topological vector spaces. Regarding your description of $M(A)$, this is fine if you know a) faithful representations exist and b) the result is independent of the choice of such. I'm looking at more general situations than just what I described, so I don't want to assume things that may not hold. The other description of $M(A)$ I know of is via double centralisers, in which case $p$ corresponds to a pair $(p,p^\sharp)$, where $p^\sharp$ is related to $p^*$, and both of these are bounded endomorphisms of $A$. Then $ap$ is $p^\sharp(a) = p(a^*)^*$.